# resetting the constructor property of prototype object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Consider the following snippet:

```
function shape(){
    this.name = "2d shape"
}

function triangle(){
    this.name = "triangle";
    this.ttest = function(){
        alert("in triangle constructor");
    }
}

function equitriangle(){
    this.name = "equitriangle"
}

var s = new shape();
triangle.prototype = s;
equitriangle.prototype = new triangle();

var et = new equitriangle();

alert(et.name); // this alerts equitriangle
et.ttest(); // this alerts in triangle constructor
alert(x.isPrototypeOf(et));// this alerts true
alert(et.constructor); // **but this alerts the shape constructor instead of the equitriangle constructor**
```

Question 1) Why do i get the shape constructor?

BUT if i add the following line before

```
equitriangle.prototype.constructor = equitriangle;
var et = new equitriangle();
....
.....
.....
alert(et.constructor); // this now alerts the equitriangle constructor which should be the expected output.
```

I have read that when a prototype object is overwritten as it has been in this case, it can lead to unexpected results and it is a good practice to "reset" the constructor

equitriangle.prototype.constructor = equitriangle;

But the above line does not make sense to me.

Question2) How does the above line make sense ?

Comment: Why does the line make no sense to you? What do you think it does?

Answer (score 2):

> Why do i get the shape constructor?

Note that `et.constructor` is a property inherited by the prototype:

```
et.constructor; // shape
et.hasOwnProperty('constructor'); // false
```

Then, `.constructor` is inherited from `equitriangle.prototype`.

But also note that `equitriangle.prototype.constructor` is inherithed from `triangle.prototype`.

But also note that `triangle.prototype.constructor` is inherithed from `shape.prototype`.

Finally, `shape.prototype.hasOwnProperty('constructor')` is `true`